# replace git submodule protocol from git to http

Tags: git, capistrano

I add a submodule from a git@... URL, to be able to develop in it.  Now I want to deploy the app and replace the URL with an git://... one, so it doesn't need authentication to the submodule's repo from Capistrano.  Is editing the URL in .gitmodules totally enough to accomplish this?

Comment: no need for sync: Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) comes with [a new command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)": `git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Editing the `.gitmodules` file (then committing, and pushing it) will be adequate for any *new* clones.

Additionally, when a submodule is initialized (e.g. `git submodule init …`, `git submodule update --init …`, or `git clone --recursive …`, etc.) its URL is copied from the `.gitmodules` file to the repository’s `.git/config` file.

So, if you have any *existing* “deployment clones” (the ones you now want to access the submodules through `git://…` URLs), you will also have to update the URL in their `.git/config`. You can use `git submodule sync` to automatically copy the submodule URLs from the current `.gitmodules` file to your `.git/config` file (i.e. once you have pulled the commit that updates the `.gitmodules` file).

The submodule URLs in `.git/config` are not normally automatically updated because there are cases where you only want to override the URL in certain situations. Specifically, you will often want to use `git@…` URLs in your repository’s `.git/config` (so you can push over SSH), but put `git://…` URLs in `.gitmodules` (so that the general public does not need to do SSH-based authentication).

Comment: git submodule sync did the job! Thanks!

Comment: Priceless answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced similar problems, and after googling, I stumbled on this article: [Relative URL for Git submodule](https://www.gniibe.org/memo/software/git/using-submodule.html). I found it's good a practice to follow as there's no need to manually change the `.gitsubmodule` file no matter who checks out it. It probably applies to your case as well.

Comment: Does it actually work only for submodules within the same hub of git repos?
What if I connect a repo from other hub as a submod? E.g. a gitlab repo has a submodule located at github?