# MonoDevelop 5.0 for Linux Distro?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, speech

According to the official website, Mono now supports System.Speech (in 5.0) . However, I am unable to reach a linux build of version 5.0

*"Packages for MonoDevelop 5.0.0.878 not yet available. The latest available version is MonoDevelop 4.2.1"*

Is there any way of achieving this? (tarballs, git?)

**Notes**

- I am using ArchLinux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to use the last monodevelop on Linux is to get it from git (it's very fast and very easy :)
Now I'm using it (5.1) on Ubuntu 14.04.

You can get the source code from here:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
```

and then compile it: http://monodevelop.com/developers/building_monodevelop

Remember that you must have installed Mono runtime 3.x.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running monodevelop-5 from ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this a little earlier but i think it applies right now too because Xamarin have already provided Mono 3.6.0 builds(technical preview) for Debian and derivatives.And with in a few months the best way to get anything latest related to mono will be from Xamarin official builds.They will provide Mono and some important applications including Monodevelop for every Debian and Centos derived Linux distributions.

**See this link......**

[mono builds for many Linux distributions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Having just built Monodevelop the hard way, I would recommend downloading a tarball from http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/ as everything is already included and requires no additional downloads except the some apt-get installs.

If you really want to use the git repo here is how to fix the two major issues I had.

1) I'm behind a proxy so I had to edit git module files to not use the git protocol as described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/11410074/1516326

2) You have to Import the Mozilla LXR certificates for Mono, so NuGet can update correctly, using:

mozroots --import --sync

For the entire process follow these instructions: http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/

Comment: How do you get it running after you download it? I assume this source tarball requires the usual steps? Read readme? Which probably says configure (some magic here), then make, then sudo make install?

Comment: My apt-get installs for debian were: `libssh2-1-dev cmake gnome-sharp2 gnome-sharp2-examples intltool `